# Carousel 3 images one at at time

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Premise**: I'm trying to create a vertical verse of the banner on [this site](https://www.victoriaroux.com/) but with 3 images showing at once where each image is a link and has a caption overlay.

**Current Problem**: I started by trying to figure out how to do a simple rotation of images without any animations.

**Research**: My first attempt was to copy [this overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32080077/how-to-create-a-vertical-carousel-using-plain-javascript-and-css) but I couldn't figure out how to make it timed.

My second attempt was trying to use [this w3schools link](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp) but I couldn't get 3 full images at a time.

Code: right now I cant figure out how to removed the first item in the list, add one to the bottom, then restart the loop. I'm still self-learning CSS and JavaScript so any explanation would be helpful.

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
var y;
var index = 0;
feed();

function feed() {
  for (y = 0; y < x.length; y++) {
    if (y > 2) {
      x[y].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  index++;
  if (index > x.length) {
    index = 1
  }

  x[index - 1].style.display = "none";

  setTimeout(feed, 1000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

```css
.slide {
  display: block;
  width:   200px;
  height:  auto;
}
.container
{
  width:   200px;
  height:  600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="slide" src="https://i.imgur.com/m9aYOcc.jpg">
  <img class="slide" src="https://i.imgur.com/fyX7DaN.jpg">
  <img class="slide" src="https://i.imgur.com/76AVqI2.jpg">
  <img class="slide" src="https://i.imgur.com/BXM4J5X.jpg">
  <img class="slide" src="https://i.imgur.com/D8f9h4q.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Where did you define `carousel()`?

Comment: @WaisKamal actually that was an oversight the post and the code. not quite working as inteaded yet

Comment: Your images are not showing. Upload them to your question first.

Comment: ive uploaded them. and added the container info too.