# How do I create arrows to scroll to the next video when clicked? HTML, CSS and Javascript specific

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

How do I achieve the above effect where, when I click the respective arrows it will scroll to reveal the next video?

I don't have any code to show, this is all for a school project and now I have to make a website based on the wireframes I came up with. I've seen this effect on a couple sites but i'm unsure on how to implement it. Can't take back the wireframes I've submitted. Please help. The videos page is the only bit of my 5 page wireframes that I'm stumped on.

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - What have you tried so far? where are you stuck? What is the issue? What research efford have you done? You should come up with an attempt at least that we can fix instead of letting us code everything for you.

Comment: yeah I thought as much fair enough I'll get as far as I can and then post my attempt. Sorry for coming off as lazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called a vertical carousel. Try to google something like "vertical image carousel html".

I was able to find some advanced
[Infinite rotating carousel with 100 list items (#cpc-100-list)](https://codepen.io/agalliat/pen/bGpjVaw) with good link in comment

```
<!-- Inspired by: https://3dtransforms.desandro.com/carousel -->
```

and [Infinite Carousel with Pure CSS and JS (ELEMENTS)](https://codepen.io/maxym11/pen/dyGEzay)

Or a simpler one, already [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32084683/7450890) on Stack

Comment: This looks like it will help I'll let you know if it does. Thanks for the suggestions. I'm new to this so if your answer does happen to work, how do I vote you as the best answer. Do I click the tick thingy?

Comment: @Bleach Glad I managed to help. 
Yes, that tick means you accept my answer.

Comment: Like I said in my first comment I was trying it out. The google search you suggested helped immensely. Sorry it took so long to accept your answer. I had to move to a python assignment (us students over here have shorter deadlines thanks to the gov) so I forgot about stack overflow in the midst of that. Point is

Comment: I digress... Thanks and I accept your answer. - A btec extended diploma IT student.